# How can I serve the content of a different website inside my sails.js app?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have a WordPress blog hosted in server A, under the domain blog.sample.com
I want to display it inside my sails.js app, under sample.com/blog, which is hosted in server B.

Preferably I'd like to do it with Sails.js, otherwise pure Node.js code it's fine.

I've looked into reverse proxies in Node.js, but I am not sure if that's why I need to do.

Comment: Not sure if i understand your question right but why not just use iframe?

Comment: Becuase I want all the SEO to benefit the main domain. And I actually want to get rid of the subdomain blog.sample.com, so the iframe will display no content.

Comment: Are you just looking to keep the content from server A? As in the blog will be displayed with the style of website B?

Comment: No, I want the blog to be displayed as is, with its own style, in its own server.
I just want to display it under the domain sample.com/blog